# filter out impoper time in R fro a dataframe containing time values

Tags: r, python-2.7

I have a dataset having some time values. But in between there are rubbish values. For example, if I have data like

```
15.15
15.20
19.30
15.40 
15.45
16.15
```

I want remove the value containing 19.30.

Comment: ??? what langage is this, a python list? Numpy array? R vector?

Comment: "rubbish" is not very clear definition of the values you want to remove.

Answer (score 1):

We can try `diff` in `R`.

```
v1[c(diff(v1)>=0, TRUE)]
#[1] 15.15 15.20 15.40 15.45 16.15
```

#### data

```
v1 <- c(15.15, 15.20,19.30, 15.4, 15.45, 16.15)
```

Comment: I'm not sure this will work in all cases correctly. For example `c(15.15, 16.3)`. I'd guess this should involve some variance measurement maybe? This question is kind of unclear IMO

Comment: @DavidArenburg You are right.  The question is not very clear.